# Virtualbox guest addition insert related

Tags: virtualbox

I've ubuntu 15 as host machine and windows virtual.
when I clicked on the insert guest addition image it says

[image: virtualbox guest additions disk image not found]

and when I clicked on download I did not download and through an error:

[image: guest additions disk image download error]

Comment: Did you have internet access at that time? Just make sure you can reach the internet, and retry.

Comment: yes my internet connection is working

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu (host) update your packages list,

`sudo apt-get update`

Install the virtualbox additions,

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions`

Next, use `right Ctrl + D` while virtual machine is running. Pressing the `Host+ D` which is `right Ctrl + D`(default)  loads the  guest-additions to virtual-machine.